# Magento - Apply Layered Navigation State / Search Results to product collection

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have multiple color variations of a product, each with a separate SKU.

To achieve the design my client requested, we

1. created a configurable product & added associated child products
2. on the product page, we removed the add to cart button, and created a table with links to the individual product color variations.

On the product list page we load all the children of the configurable product, and inserted a table containing links for each color variation to the child products.

We used the following code

```
<?php if($_product->isConfigurable()){
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
        ->setProduct($_product);
$col = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
       ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq'=>'1'))
       ->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
```

I then use this collection to populate a table which contains links to the child products.

I would like to only show the products which have the color value which was selected in layered navigation -- meaning for example a configurable product which comes in black, white and green, I want that when a user selects green from the layered navigation filter, this collection should only contain the green child product.

I would like this functionality to work for search as well, so for example, when a user searches for a sku which only matches one of the children, that should be the only child which would be loaded in the collection shown above.

Any ideas?